# Rotating image gallery

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```
function RotatingImageGallery() {
      return (
        <main>
          <div className="box">
            <span styles="--i:1;">
              <img src={Picture1} alt="" />
            </span>
            <span styles="--i:2;">
              <img src={Picture2} alt="" />
            </span>
            <span styles="--i:3;">
              <img src={Picture3} alt="" />
            </span>
            <span styles="--i:4;">
              <img src={Picture4} alt="" />
            </span>
            <span styles="--i:5;">
              <img src={Picture5} alt="" />
            </span>
            <span styles="--i:6;">
              <img src={Picture1} alt="" />
            </span>
            <span styles="--i:7;">
              <img src={Picture2} alt="" />
            </span>
            <span styles="--i:8;">
              <img src={Picture3} alt="" />
            </span>
          </div>
        </main>
      );
    }
```

This is my code in a JS file, React Component, and I want to build a rotating image gallery, but in the CSS code there is a problem somewhere, because I only see the last picture in the middle and its just rotates around its own axis..

Here is my CSS Part :

```
.box span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--i) * 45deg)) translateZ(400px);
  -webkit-box-reflect: below 0px
    linear-gradient(transparent, transparent, #0004);
}
```

In the transform section I think there is the problem, but I don't know why, in a simple HTML file this works fine. Please help me, any ideas?

Comment: you are making all the element position:absolute on the top of each other

Comment: yes, but it works in html+css combination and the code is the same.